# Haskell operate on the return value of a lookup call

Tags: haskell

I have the following code (using lookup from the Haskell Prelude):

```
al :: [(Char, Int)]
al = [("A", 1),
      ("B", 2),
      ("C", 3),
      ...
 ]

strToInt :: [Char] -> Int
strToInt []
 = 0
strToInt (c:cs)
 = lookup c al + strToInt cs
```

The problem is I am trying to perform addition on `Maybe Int` and `Int` which the compiler will not allow. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: What, in your opinion, is supposed to happen if the string contains characters that do not occur in `a1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, since you're adding values together, and it'd be natural to ignore `Nothing` values (i.e. treat them as `0`), you could also write the function using `mapMaybe`:

```
import Data.Maybe (mapMaybe)

al :: [(Char, Int)]
al = [('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3)]

strToInt :: String -> Int
strToInt = sum . mapMaybe (`lookup` al)
```

GHCi:

```
*Q46515794> strToInt "AB"
3
*Q46515794> strToInt "AC"
4
*Q46515794> strToInt "ABC"
6
```

Answer (score 1):

If the precondition is that the lookup will always be successful, use `fromJust :: Maybe a -> a` to parse the value - for example, `fromJust (lookup c al)`.

Otherwise, you will need some 'default' value (e.g. `0`) to return in case the lookup fails. Then you can use `fromMaybe :: a -> Maybe a -> a` which takes the default value as the first parameter and parses the value - for example, `fromMaybe 0 (lookup c a1)`.

Comment: Those aren't the only two possibilities: they might want to propagate a `Nothing` with `(+) <$> lookup c a1 <*> strToInt cs`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to have control on  your logic. It is not known what you want when the character you provide returns `Nothing`, this function better return a `Maybe` type.

If you want to treat `Nothing`s as `0` then `mapMaybe` is one way to go. Or if you want a `Maybe` type result then...

```
al :: [(Char, Int)]
al = [('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3), ('D', 4)]

strToInt :: [(Char, Int)] -> String -> Maybe Int
strToInt ts cs = foldr (\c m -> (+) <$> (lookup c ts) <*> m) (Just 0) cs

*Main> strToInt al "AJN"
Nothing
*Main> strToInt al "ABCD"
Just 10
```